# Is this UTF8-to-code-point example correct?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

From [this site](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/UTF-8_encode_and_decode#C)

```
typedef struct {
    char mask;    /* char data will be bitwise AND with this */
    char lead;    /* start bytes of current char in utf-8 encoded character */
    uint32_t beg; /* beginning of codepoint range */
    uint32_t end; /* end of codepoint range */
    int bits_stored; /* the number of bits from the codepoint that fits in char */
}utf_t;

utf_t * utf[] = {
    /*             mask        lead        beg      end       bits */
    [0] = &(utf_t){0b00111111, 0b10000000, 0,       0,        6    },
    [1] = &(utf_t){0b01111111, 0b00000000, 0000,    0177,     7    },
    [2] = &(utf_t){0b00011111, 0b11000000, 0200,    03777,    5    },
    [3] = &(utf_t){0b00001111, 0b11100000, 04000,   0177777,  4    },
    [4] = &(utf_t){0b00000111, 0b11110000, 0200000, 04177777, 3    },
          &(utf_t){0},
};

uint32_t to_cp(const char chr[4])
{
    int bytes = utf8_len(*chr);
    int shift = utf[0]->bits_stored * (bytes - 1);
    uint32_t codep = (*chr++ & utf[bytes]->mask) << shift;

    for(int i = 1; i < bytes; ++i, ++chr) {
        shift -= utf[0]->bits_stored;
        codep |= ((char)*chr & utf[0]->mask) << shift;
    }

    return codep;
}
```

It looks to me like the two lines in the loop should use `utf[i]` not `utf[0]`, like this:

```
        shift -= utf[i]->bits_stored;
        codep |= ((char)*chr & utf[i]->mask) << shift;
```

Is that right?

Comment: How and where is `utf` array defined? Please include all necessary code in the question (create [mcve]).

Comment: links to external web pages can disappear.  Please copy/post the actual code, not some link to the code

Comment: binary constants are a `gcc` extension,  so the linked code will not compile with other compilers

Comment: the code at the linked web page doesn't even come close to compiling,

Comment: Regardless of compiler and language -- is the *algorithm* correct?

Comment: well, what are you trying (or the code is trying) to accomplish?

Comment: As the title of the question indicates, it's a UTF8-to-code-point algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`utf[0]` is correct. That entry applies to all trailing bytes; `utf[j]` describes the initial byte in a sequence of length `j`.